# why I am getting Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

why I am getting Cannot read property 'map' of undefined while maping data..?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { AllData } from "./api";

const Home = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  const getData = async () => {
    const res = await AllData();

    setData(res);
    console.log(res);

    console.log(res);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((items) => {
        <div>{items.topic}</div>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Here is my data screenshot [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twbLo.jpg)

Comment: Add an empty array as the default state `useState([]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const [data, setData] = useState();
```

You did not give any value for the `useState` function. `useState` should have initial value for the state as a parameter. As you give nothing, `data` is set as `undefined`
That's the reason you should change it like this.

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript *map* method only works for arrays. You are initializing the state as empty.
You can add an initial state for `data` as

```
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```

Also, you can render only if `data` is not empty ,

```
return (
    <div>
      {data.length && data.map((items) => {
        <div>{items.topic}</div>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
```